# 360 Camera lags in middle of animation

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

I'm want to create a 360 camera animation that features the entire kitchen at a linear interpolation. However, there is a lag around frame 8050 and then speeds up at around frame 8070.

The graph editor shows a linear graph, so thats not the problem. I've increased the resolution preview to 60 on the circular path that the camera follows in order to decrease the choppiness of the camera view. I do noticed that the frame rate is dropping significantly more during the problematic frames. Will this problem be magically fixed after render or is there something I am doing wrong?

Link to dropbox video, showing the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l4tmis86vopu380/Camera%20Lag.mov?dl=0

Comment: pls provide blend file, because the video just shows the result. But without blend file we cannot find the cause - we can just guess.

Comment: The playback FPS is lower, most likely because there are more objects to draw in the middle of the animation so it takes more time per frame. But if you render the animation there shouldn't be any hiccup

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance @Gorgious. Is there a way to improve fps or bake in the keyframes for preview before the actual render?

Comment: You can try to enable "Simplify" in the scene settings and disable subdivision levels there if you have any subdivided objets

Comment: Thank you @Gorgious. There is still lag when I turn the subdivision down to 0 in the scene settings. However, like you said, it may just that there are more objects.